# how can I get requests(module name) data parameter to my dJango server?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

my tkinter app

```
def _calculation(self):
    myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test"
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(myList))
```

my dJango Server

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    print(request.data) # why error happen?
    return HttpResponse('')
```

I am making a tkinter app(front) and django Server(back) post matching, but I can't get requests(module name) data(request parameter) from django server. how can I get requests data parameter

Comment: What is the error message? [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/) objects don't have an attribute called `.data`.

Comment: sorry i skip error code :  
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Yeah, basically what I wrote above. Click the link I provided to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AttributeError: '**WSGIRequest**' object has no attribute '**data**'
but you can use `request.body` like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    print(request.body)
    return HttpResponse('')
```